# Black screen after login on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, grub2

I have tried setting nomodeset in the grub, I tried switching between kernels 5.19 and 6.2, the former worked at first, but none of my browsers worked.

As of now, nothing seems to work. I am thinking its time to actually use a virtual machine and not dual booting anymore.

Comment: sounds like you don't have the right video driver installed.  But you didn't give any details of hardware or drivers installed...